# Не сериализуется класс с помощью System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, winforms

Класс:

```
[Serializable]
internal class Exercise
{
    internal string Name { get; set; }
    internal string Desription { get; set; }
    internal string StartCode { get; set; }
    internal string[] Answers { get; set; }
    internal int GoodAnswer { get; set; }
    public string work;
}
```

Сериализую:

```
Exercise ex = new Exercise
{
    Answers = new string[] { "Who Trahat" , "ANY"},
    Desription = "Find Hagy-Wagy???",
    GoodAnswer = 0,//"Blue Hagy-Wagy",
    Name = "Hagy-Wagy",
    StartCode = @"SHO
    NUSHO
    Console."
};
ex.work = "qq";
File.WriteAllText(Wrapper.path + "\\1", JsonSerializer.Serialize(ex, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
}));
```

В файле получается: {}
Знаю что часто у многих проблемы с тем, что они забывают добавить атрибут [Serializable]. у меня же это не решило проблему

Comment: Потому что сериализация, как и многие другие вещи с передачей данных, работают исключительно с **публичными свойствами**. И да, `Serializable` вешать бессмысленно!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Я ради этого и сделал Work, везде видел что люди используют и переменные, переменные в других либах возможно использовать?
Помогло, сделайте ответ

Comment: Просто запомните, для передачи данных, делают так называемые DTO объекты, а это публичные классы с публичными свойствами, без какой-либо логики, лишь чтоб взять, быстро создать и передать. Дальше уже все конечно зависит от целей и др. аспектов программы, нужны, например поля - включите опцию `IncludeFields`, но опять же, **только публичные**. Ну а ответ, делайте сами, я бы если хотел, то наверно уже сделал?)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ дан @EvgeniyZ

1. `[Serializable]` не важен
2. Json работает только с публичными свойствами
3. Если хотите использовать ещё и публичные поля - используйте опцию `IncludeFields`

Правильный вид Класса:

```
internal class Exercise
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desription { get; set; }
    public string StartCode { get; set; }
    public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    public int GoodAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Сериализация и десериализация JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview)